# The requested URL returned error: 502 when running git clone inside a Docker container

Tags: git, docker

I have a simple bash script `git clone https://x-token-auth:$REPOSITORY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN@bitbucket.org/danechitoaie/open-pipelines-test1.git $BUILD_DIR` that I run in a Docker container and the problem is that sometimes git clone fails with following error message `fatal: unable to access 'https://x-token-auth:$REPOSITORY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN@bitbucket.org/danechitoaie/open-pipelines-test1.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502`

This happens randomly, so sometimes it works sometimes I get this error.

Any idea what could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also get random 502 errors from bitbucket since yesterday, so I'd assume bitbucket has currently some issues.

Comment: I was thinking so too. I'd try to run git clone locally from my PC to compare but the problem is random so it's hard to reproduce. Lately seems to be working and no longer had the issue. I'm new to Docker so I thought maybe there are some extra settings that need to be done or something like that. But the fact that I do get a HTTP error and I clone using HTTP makes me agree that error is coming from Bitbucket side, as it's the only http involved in this whole process.

Answer (score 3):

The 502 http response means "Bad gateway". So you have some kind of connection problem to the repository. I think the problem is not related to docker. Probably on the host machine containing your Docker containers you'll have the same behavior if you try the git clone to the repository. Test it if you can.

You said it happens randomly. Are you behind a proxy or something similar? That issue happens sometimes under that proxy scenario. If that is your case, remember to put ENV var in your Dockerfiles with the proxy settings:

```
ENV http_proxy http://x.x.x.x:xxxx
ENV https_proxy https://x.x.x.x:xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue in my company while clone a repository from GitHub, that may caused by your host machine network proxy configuration.

I don't know your network environment, but in my company, if you want visit Internet, you must config a proxy.

I edited .gitconfig by `vim ~/.gitconfig`, change to another http proxy server

```sh
........
[http]
        proxy = http://username:password@anotherproxy.mycompany.com:8080
[https]
        proxy = https://username:password@anotherproxy.mycompany.com:8080
        sslVerify = false
.....
```

and run `git clone https://github.com/somesuer/someproject.git`, it works